# У меня не работает сеттор,скажите почему?

Tags: javascript, объекты, get, obj, set

```js
let dom = {
  number: 8,
  get sort(){
   return this.number;
  },
  set sort(value){
    if(value >= 0 && value <= 4){
      this.number = value;
    }else{
      console.log("Число должно быть меньше 4");
    }
  }
};

console.log(dom.sort);
```

Comment: Потому что у вас опечатка.

Comment: Где опечатка?Уточните пожалуйста

Comment: numder .............

Comment: НЕ помогло!!!!!

Comment: @VladislavLoza помогло!!!!!

Comment: Если число больше 4 оно должно вывести "Число должно быть меньше 4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let dom = {
  number: 8,
  get sort(){
    if(this.number >= 0 && this.number <= 4){
      return this.number;
    }else{
      return "Число должно быть меньше 4";
    }
  },
  set sort(value){
    if(value >= 0 && value <= 4){
      this.number = value;
    }else{
      console.log("Число должно быть меньше 4");
    }
  }
};

console.log(dom.sort);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: УЖЕ И SET НЕ НУЖЕН

Comment: let dom = {
  number: 8,
  get sort(){
    if(this.number >= 0 && this.number <= 4){
      return this.number;
    }else{
      return "Число должно быть меньше 4";
    }
  },
};

console.log(dom.sort);

Answer (score 0):

```
let dom = {
  number: 8,
  get sort(){
   return this.number;
  },
  set sort(value){
    if(value >= 0 && value <= 4){
      this.number = value;
    } else {
      console.log("Число должно быть меньше 4")
    }
  }
};

console.log(dom.sort);
dom.sort = 5;
console.log(dom.sort);
```

У вас dom.sort = 3 - а это меньше 4, по этому условие true

Comment: При вызове,dom.sort выдаёт 8

Comment: ну так this.number = value не срабатывает, когда value > 4

Comment: Значит должно вывестись "Число должно быть меньше 4"

Comment: Он и выводится при попытке задать значение.

Comment: Значение number уже задано!!!!!!!!

Comment: Оно и выводиться, как вы сейчас...

Comment: При попытке ПРИСВОИТЬ новое значение (5), срабатывает setter.
В нем условие, если value <= 4 тогда значение у объекта dom меняется на заданное, иначе выводиться текст, но значение остается прежним!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

СОКРАЩЕННЫЙ ВАРИАНТ

```
let dom = {
  number: 8,
  get sort(){
    if(this.number >= 0 && this.number <= 4){
      return this.number;
    }else{
      return "Число должно быть меньше 4";
    }
  },
};

console.log(dom.sort);
```